# Blur image and show text over image (css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I have 2 images, which upon hover over I'd like to blur and show text on top. However, currently it appears that the images only blur when the cursor is at its edge but not when the cursor is in the middle. I'd like the image to blur AND show its text. Does anyone have advice on where I might be going wrong?

Also, any advice on how to better position the text *within* the images would be great. I think my "position" or "display" is off. Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<style media="screen">
  .study-icons {
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* border: 2px solid blue; */
  }

  .study-icons:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
  }

  .study-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .img__wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 255px;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .img__description_layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10;
    right: 0;
    /* background: rgba(36, 62, 206, 0.6); */
    color: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* transition effect. not necessary */
    transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
  }

  .img__wrap:hover .img__description_layer {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .img__description {
    transition: .2s;
    transform: translateY(1em);
  }

  .img__wrap:hover .img__description {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="img__wrap">
    <div id="image1">
      <img class="img__img study-icons" src="assets/studies/image1.png">
      <div class="img__description_layer">
        <p class="img__description">Sample text here about image1?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img__wrap">
    <div id="image2">
      <img class="img__img study-icons" src="assets/studies/image2.png">
      <div class="img__description_layer">
        <p class="img__description">Sample text here about image2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this please assign the hovering to be on the **img__wrap**

In order to make sure your text centered you have to make the .ing__wrap positioned as relative, then set the .img__description_layer to be like this:

```
Position:absolute;
Top:50%;
Left:50%;
Transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Comment: thanks so much! This works better than before, but when I hover over the area where the text is itself, the blur effect goes away. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: You need to do it this way **.study-icons:hover img {-webkit-filter: blur(10px);filter: blur(10px); }**